# Apex Trigger Test Class Coverage

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to create a test class for my apex trigger but I am not able to reach the code coverage. does anyone how I can reach the code coverage?

Here is trigger

```
trigger AccountInformation on Charter__c (Before Update) 
{
for(Charter__c c: trigger.new)
{
   List<Account> accts = [SELECT Invoice_Contact_1_Email__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_2_Email__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_3_Name__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_2_Name__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_1_Name__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_3_Phone__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_2_Phone__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_1_Phone__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_3_Email__c
                         FROM account WHERE ID =:c.Account__c];
   for (Account a: Accts)
   {
       c.Invoice_Contact_1__c = a.Invoice_Contact_1_Name__c;
         c.Invoice_Contact_2__c = a.Invoice_Contact_2_Name__c;
       c.Invoice_Contact_3__c = a.Invoice_Contact_3_Name__c;
       c.Invoice_Contact_1_Phone__c = a.Invoice_Contact_1_Phone__c;
       c.Invoice_Contact_2_Phone__c = a.Invoice_Contact_2_Phone__c;
       c.Invoice_Contact_3_Phone__c = a.Invoice_Contact_3_Phone__c;
       c.Invoice_Contact_1_Email__c = a.Invoice_Contact_1_Email__c;
       c.Invoice_Contact_2_Email__c = a.Invoice_Contact_2_Email__c;
       c.Invoice_Contact_3_Email__c = c.Invoice_Contact_3_Email__c;

   }
}
}
```

This trigger is suppose to insert values from an account to my custom object called charter before an update to the record. I have tested this in the sandbox and it is working well.

Here is my test class

```
@isTest
private class AccountingInforTesting {
  static testMethod void Test_Infor(){

  charter__c con = new charter__c(name='Test Charter 10', Account__c = '001Z000000eX3xlIAC', DCS__c = True);
  insert Con;
  con.name = 'Test';
  update con;
  delete con;
   }
}
```

The test class has given me only 25% of code coverage.

Any help on how I can make this work is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You're not using `@isTest(SeeAllData=true)`, but you're using a hard-coded ID value. Change your test as follows:

```
@isTest
private class AccountingInforTesting {
  static testMethod void Test_Infor(){
  account acc = new account(name='test');
  insert acc;
  charter__c con = new charter__c(name='Test Charter 10', Account__c = acc.id, DCS__c = True);
  insert Con;
  con.name = 'Test';
  update con;
  delete con;
   }
}
```

### Edit

Your trigger isn't bulk-safe, either. Use a map instead:

```
trigger AccountInformation on Charter__c (Before Update) 
{
  map<id, account> accs = new map<id, account>();
  for(charter__c c: trigger.new)
    accs.put(c.account__c, null);
  accs.remove(null);
  accs.putall([SELECT Invoice_Contact_1_Email__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_2_Email__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_3_Name__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_2_Name__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_1_Name__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_3_Phone__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_2_Phone__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_1_Phone__c,
                                 Invoice_Contact_3_Email__c
                         FROM account WHERE ID in :accs.keyset()]);
for(Charter__c c: trigger.new)
{
   if(accs.containskey(c.account__c)) {
       account a = accs.get(c.account__c);
       c.Invoice_Contact_1__c = a.Invoice_Contact_1_Name__c;
       c.Invoice_Contact_2__c = a.Invoice_Contact_2_Name__c;
       c.Invoice_Contact_3__c = a.Invoice_Contact_3_Name__c;
       c.Invoice_Contact_1_Phone__c = a.Invoice_Contact_1_Phone__c;
       c.Invoice_Contact_2_Phone__c = a.Invoice_Contact_2_Phone__c;
       c.Invoice_Contact_3_Phone__c = a.Invoice_Contact_3_Phone__c;
       c.Invoice_Contact_1_Email__c = a.Invoice_Contact_1_Email__c;
       c.Invoice_Contact_2_Email__c = a.Invoice_Contact_2_Email__c;
       c.Invoice_Contact_3_Email__c = c.Invoice_Contact_3_Email__c;
    }
  }
}
```